# C# Using String to identify/use a textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have 6 text boxes in 6 lines, 36 in all. Line one, box one is called L1N1, line one, box two is L1N2 etc. I want to dynamically assign values to these text boxes using a string...can this be done in C#? E.g.

```
    private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[,] numbers = new int[6, 6];
        int lin = 0;
        while (lin < 6)
        {
            lin++;
            int num = 0;
            while (num < 6)
            {
                num++;
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomNum = random.Next(1, 45);
                "L" + lin + "N" + num /* <--here is my string (L1N1) i want to 
                                          set my textbox(L1N1).text to a value
                                          randomNum!*/
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't have these textboxes in collections? Why would you want to identify a control by a *string* rather than a more natural indexing into a collection?

Comment: You're recreating a Random instance in a tight loop, the results are not going to be very random.

Comment: Thanks Henk, i have a Thread.Sleep in the actual code...

Comment: I think Henk is inviting you to create the Random ouside the loop, and reusing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I echo Jon Skeet's sentiments. If you want to be able to locate a control by some row/column system, the easiest way to do so is to put the controls themselves into a collection that allows them to be indexed in a similar way:

```
var textboxes = new TextBox[6][];
textboxes[0] = new TextBox[]{txtL1N1, txtL1N2, txtL1N3, txtL1N4, txtL1N5, txtL1N6};
//create the rest of the "lines" of TextBoxes similarly.

//now you can reference the TextBox at Line X, number Y like this:
textboxes[X-1][Y-1].Text = randomNum.ToString();
```

Now, if you REALLY wanted to access these textboxes by some string value, you would use the Tag property, which is a general-purpose property of most Controls. You could also name all your textboxes according to some system. Then, a little Linq can get you the textbox you want:

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
   .Single(t=>t.Tag.ToString() == "L1N1").Text = randomNum.ToString();
```

However, understand this will be VERY slow; you'll be searching the full collection of all controls that exist on the Form  every time you want one. Indexing will be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the WebPage has a nice FindControl for you:

```
TextBox tx = FindControl("L" + lin + "N" + num) as TextBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TextBox> listOfTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
...initialization of list.... 
foreach(TextBox tb in listOfTextBoxes)
{
Random r = new Random();
tb.Text = r.Next(1,45).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the FindControl API and set the .text property?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Controls.Find("Your Concatenated ID of control ex: L1N2", true);
}
```

or

```
foreach(var cont in form.Controls)
{
     if(cont is TextBox) dosmth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is webform:  (just find out the form index)

> ```
>     protected void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         foreach(Control item in Page.Controls[3].Controls)
>         {
>             if(item.GetType().ToString().ToLower().Contains("textbox"))
>             {
>                 Random rnd = new Random();
>                 TextBox txt = (TextBox)item;
>                 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
>                 txt.Text = rnd.Next(1, 45).ToString();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Form.Controls has a FindByName method, so you could build the control name and use that. It's not brill though.

Personally I'd either create the controls programatically from TextBox[6,6], or at a push
load references to them from Form.Controls into an array[6,6] as a one off.

Once you have the array you can find all sorts of uses for it.